# how to return a value from a callback function in ECMAS6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a question, how can i get a variable value (in my example array variable) outside of a callback function? Here is my code!

```
var Db = require("../database/databaseInit");
var array = [];

class DBManager{
getUsers() {
        Db.find({}, function (err, users) {

            users.forEach(function (element) {  
            array.push(element.username);
            console.log(array) //here prints the users that i have in DB file
            });
        });
         console.log(array) // but here prints []
         return array;`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `console.log` in your code actually gets called first, before the database operation is complete, hence it is empty.

Change `getUsers` to accept a callback and invoke that once the database operation is complete and `arrays` is populated.

```
class DBManager {
    getUsers(done) {
        Db.find({}, function (err, users) {
            var array = [];
            users.forEach(function (element) {  
                array.push(element.username);
                console.log(array) //here prints the users that i have in DB file
            });
            done(array);
        });
    }
}

new DBManager().getUsers(function (array) {
    console.log(array);
});
```

You should read about [how asynchronous operations work in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). At the moment you are treating them as synchronous.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked! Yes I am new on javascript, need to tread them asyn !

Answer (score 0):

`getUsers` is defined by passing a callback as a parameter. When calling `getUsers`, you try to `console.log` `array` and to `return` it, however, your problem is that `console.log` and `return` are actually executed **before** the callback is being called.

Flow:

- `getUsers` is called
- `console.log` and `return`
- the request is completed and the callback is executed

You have a code somewhere which calls `getUsers` and expects its output to be a valid `array`. You need to write a `function` with the part starting from using the result of `getUsers` and take that part out from the code where it was. The new `function` should have a parameter for `array` and you should call the `function` with `array` as the last operation of your callback. You might need to check the `length` of `array` whether it matches the expected `length` before calling your `function`.